# What are minimum lines of codes for Heroku's package.json file?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am building and deploying successfully to Heroku master. But the node.js app does not work. (The system does not specify the error.)

I have two files in my folder:

1. index.js
2. package.json

The index.js file contains minimum code to create a server in vanilla node.js. The package.json file contains this code, and I suspect I need to add something. Your help is very much appreciated!

```html
{
"name": "siatest88",
"description": "Our sampe Node to",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing a similar problem. It's worth typing "heroku logs" into the console. This revealed the following error.

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Stopping process with SIGKILL
Process exited with status 137
State changed from starting to crashed
```

The problem was in the index.js file. The port needs to be defined as "let port = process.env.PORT || 80". Then it works.

It seems that the minimalist package.json file in my original post is sufficient to configure on Heroku correctly.